# Laravel group by x number of rows

Tags: php, sql, laravel, fetch

Could i fetch data groupBy X number of rows like

```
[
   [row1, row2, row3],
   [row4, row5, row6],
   [row7, row8, row9],
   [row10, row11, row12],
   ....
]
```

Comment: Could you? Yes, you could

Comment: well gotta give it to you, it is a "question"

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-chunk

Answer (score 0):

You can format your results that way using the `chunk()` collection method.

```php
$results = DB::table(...)->......->get();

foreach ($results->chunk(3) as $chunk) {
    foreach ($chunk as $result) {
        ...
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-chunk